# Explanation regarding to typedef and vectors

Tags: c++

I need to store the size of a vector named homework and i don't know how to do that i came up with this by the help of a book but didn't understood can someone explain every term used here?

```
 typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
vec_sz size=homework.size();
```

Comment: What parts of this *do* you understand?

Comment: What about the code don't you understand?  Did you look up how typedef works?  Did you check the [reference for vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to see what `size_type` is?

Comment: "explain every term used here?" is a matter of a months long course if one assumes nothing. You have to be more specific. What exactly dont you understand?

Comment: @ScottHunter i am a very beginner and i am reading a book named accelerated c++ by andrew koenig but i am not able to understand what typedef is and what work is done in those 2 lines that's why i am asking.

Comment: @ScottHunter i know what a vector is and what size_type, double and size() is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef X Y;` is telling that an existing type `X` is from now on also known as `Y`.

`vec_sz size = homework.size();`

is then the same as

`std::vector<double>::size_type size = homework.size();`

and thats even same as

`auto size = homework.size();`

`std::vector<double>::size_type` is a member type of class `std::vector<double>` and it is the same as `std::size_t`